# I referred to vue.js formula, but I get an error

Tags: vue.js

At the beginning, the [official](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/index.html#Component-data-essential) word is this

```
data: function () {
  return {
    listTitle: '',
    todos: []
  }
}
```

this is my code

```
<script>
import Seached from "@/components/index.vue";
  data: function() {
    return {
      a: '',
      b: '',
      c: ''
    }
  }
</script>
```

I got the error

> In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or inside a block

I can't figure out the solution even after looking at the formula, how should I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your code like as following

```
 <script>
    import Seached from "./components/index.vue";
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                a:'',
                b:'',
                c:''
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If I want to use it in v-model instead of taking it to another component, is it okay to write it that way?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. v-model is used for input binding. (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

Comment: How do I describe a non-external reference?